# C - Reshape 2D array in runtime

Tags: c, arrays

How can a 2D array be re-shaped in runtime, in C? 
For example, we have initially declared a unsigned char array[20][500] and need later to re-shape it, to something like e.g. array[40][250]. The total memory consumption will (and must) always stay the same (10.000 bytes).

The restrain is that the newly shaped array, must be on the exact memory space address - as initially was declared. We can't allocate a different space / we are not sure if there will be any free space to use (microprocessor project). 
I tried with calloc, but eventually it goes bananas:

```
unsigned char **my_array; //Global defined

void reshape(unsigned short max_cols, unsigned short max_rows){
    my_array = (unsigned char **) calloc(max_cols, sizeof(unsigned char*));
    for(i = 0; i < max_cols; ++i){
        my_array[i] = (unsigned char **) calloc(max_rows, sizeof(unsigned char));
    }
}
```

I am a newbie in C, so any help is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: *"must be on the exact memory space address"* - that's only possible with a custom allocation function, none of the standard ones provide this guarantee

Comment: You could implement a one-dimensional array and manage the indexing yourself. For example `array[row * width + column]`.

Comment: If you have a fixed-sized constraint, then using a single long array and using indexing to access it differently is the best and simplest way (as shown by @WeatherVane). Otherwise if you need to keep it as a jagged array (like you do with `unsigned char **`) then just free the memory you already have allocated, and allocate it anew with the new dimensions.

Comment: @WeatherVane: That is a very clever idea, will be my last resort, as I have to re-write a lot of stuff to use the new type of pointer.
I was wondering if I can initially declare / reserve the space needed (10.000 bytes) in a way to get the pointer for this space, and then format it as needed - like UnholySheep speculated

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, as I am a newbie, can you show me a line of code to test & understand this?

Comment: You have shown us the code to allocate your array. I assume you also have some code to `free` the memory you allocate? Then just call the function to free the currently allocated memory, and call `reshape` with the new dimensions.

Comment: By the way, in C you [should not cast the result of `malloc` (or its siblings like `calloc`)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Answer (score 0):

Array reshaping can be accomplished with casting:

```
char (*p)[FirstColumns] = calloc(FirstRows, sizeof *p);
// Test p and handle error if NULL.
char (*q)[SecondColumns] = (char (*)[SecondColumns]) p;
```

As long as the underlying elements are the same type, there should not be any aliasing issues.

(A pedantic C interpretation might question whether accessing an array of `SecondColumns` that was originally an array of `FirstColumns`, or part of it, or overlapping several, violates aliasing rules, but arrays are not actually accessed through their lvalues, as their lvalues are converted to pointers. I am not aware of any compiler that produces problems with such code.)

Answer (score 0):

So, you actually want a memory buffer, and then you have different arrays of pointers, which point to this memory buffer.

So, using globals (ugly), something like:

```
unsigned char *my_data; // allocate to have enough space, 10000 chars or whatever

unsigned char **my_array; //Global defined

void reshape(unsigned short max_cols, unsigned short max_rows) {
    free(my_array); // don't leak memory

    // no need for cast below
    // also, since array will be initialized below, use malloc
    my_array = malloc(max_cols * sizeof(unsigned char*)); 

    // initialize my_data with addresses of rows
    for(i = 0; i < max_cols; ++i) {
        my_array[i] = &(my_data[i * max_rows]);
    }
}
```

---

Though note that unless you really need `my_array` to be array of pointers, you can avoid the indirection by directly accessing mydata like this:

```
my_data[row_index * max_cols + column_index]
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @hyde! In my mind I had it like: "dear compiler, reserve 10000 bytes starting at a memory location e.g. 0x80003000", and then give me two options: "format this specific memory space as my_array[20][500] or my_array[40][250]". Looks like I can't do that... 
The other pointing method you proposed (as others did too), is a good one, but needs me to rewrite other sections of my code to work. Also, doing multiplications & addtions to calc the pointer, means extra CPU cycles, and this costs speed in a microprocessor project. :-(

Comment: @Papaki Unless you have some low-MHz embedded CPU, indirection through an extra pointer table is probably *significantly* slower than multiplication+addition.

Comment: In C you can typedef a local VLA type, which creates basically the same machine code as multiplication+addition, except with cleaner syntax and compiler generating the calculation. It might suit your purpose, if you just want the syntax, and don't actually need the pointer array for other reasons. If you want a `typedef` example, add short example function using the data to your question.

Comment: If you do need the pointer array, then the pointer array actually contains pointers to start of each row. If row length changes, then these pointers must be changed to match, there is no magic solution to *that*.

Comment: Oh, and if it isn't clear to you, there are actually two kinds of "2-dimensional array" in C commonly used. One is more like "jagged array" (because each row can be of different length), where you have 1-dimensional array of pointers to 1-dimensional arrays of row data (which don't need to be one block of memory, or in any kind of order). And then you can have actual 2-dimensional (or more) array, where data is continuous and compiler must know the extra dimensions so it can calculate the offset.